# How do you record audio from command line with osx?

Tags: command-line, audio

I've tried ffmpeg but there is no /dev/dsp device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) or [Ecasound](http://www.eca.cx/ecasound/).

Comment: Those could work but I'd really like to have a ffmpeg solution because I alredy use it for other things.

Comment: Apparently ffmpeg supports Mac audio recording out of the box if built with [OpenAL](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#SEC65). So go right ahead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking into MPlayer OSX Extended -- it's a port of the linux app "mplayer" and will let you record from a multitude of audio sources (including streams and remote files).

```
/Applications/MPlayer\ OSX\ Extended.app/Contents/Resources/Binaries/mpextended.mpBinaries/Contents/mpextended.mpBinaries/Contents/MacOS/mplayer \
    http://server.com/stream.pl \
    -cache 1024 -ao coreaudio:device_id=49 -volume 65 -ac hwac3, -slave \
    -identify -noar -dumpstream -dumpfile ~/Desktop/stream.mp3
```

See http://www.mplayerosx.ch/ for more information